# Assertion failed in Wijmo: Date expected

Tags: wijmo

While using wijmo input date control **wj-input-date** error coming Assertion failed in Wijmo: Date expected.

`<wj-input-date [(value)]="_deal.AppReceived" [format]="'M/d/yyyy'" class="ibox1 rightalign"  [placeholder]="'M/d/yyyy'" [required]="false"></wj-input-date>`

same while using **wj-input-number** error coming `Assertion failed in Wijmo: Number expected`

`<wj-input-number [(value)]="_deal.TotalCommitment"  class="ibox1 rightalign" [format]="'n2'"></wj-input-number>`

Comment: any luck on this one? having the same issue

Comment: download and install TypeScript_Dev14Full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import directive in Typescript

import { WjInputModule } from 'wijmo/wijmo.angular2.input';

use html

```
 <wj-input-number #TotalCommitment [isRequired]="false" [(value)]="TotalCommitment"  class="ibox1 rightalign" [format]="'n2'"></wj-input-number>
```